# c# USB parsing of a _URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER packet

Tags: c#, windows, usb

I'm parsing a _URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER  packet as defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540352(v=vs.85).aspx using the following code:

```
            //parse URB Packet
            /*
            _URB_HEADER {
            USHORT      Length;
            USHORT      Function;
            USBD_STATUS Status;
            PVOID       UsbdDeviceHandle;
            ULONG       UsbdFlags;
            }*/

            //start header parse
            UInt16 urb_length = rdr.ReadUInt16();
            UInt16 urb_function = rdr.ReadUInt16();
            UInt32 urb_status = rdr.ReadUInt32();
            rdr.ReadBytes(System.IntPtr.Size);
            UInt32 UsbdFlags = rdr.ReadUInt32();
            //end header parse

            //.. skip code to check if it a _URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER 
            // but assuming it is parse it

            /*struct _URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER {
            struct URB_HEADER  Hdr;//covered above
            USBD_PIPE_HANDLE    PipeHandle;
            ULONG               TransferFlags;
            ULONG               TransferBufferLength;
            PVOID               TransferBuffer;
            PMDL                TransferBufferMDL;
            struct URB  *UrbLink;
            struct URB_HCD_AREA  hca;
            }*/

            rdr.ReadBytes(System.IntPtr.Size);
            UInt32 TransferFlags = rdr.ReadUInt32();
            UInt32 TransferBufferLength = rdr.ReadUInt32();
            byte[] ptr_bytes = rdr.ReadBytes(System.IntPtr.Size);
            System.IntPtr ptr_transfer_buffer = new System.IntPtr(BitConverter.ToUInt32(ptr_bytes, 0));
            ptr_bytes = rdr.ReadBytes(System.IntPtr.Size);
            System.IntPtr mdl_transfer_buffer = new System.IntPtr(BitConverter.ToUInt32(ptr_bytes, 0))
```

Inspecting all the values as they are being read in, most seem sensible until the PMDL void pointer. This ends up being a large negative number instead of 0 (NULL) or a valid address. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDL objects are memory descriptors only usable in kernel mode. Due to the user/kernel-mode split, virtual addresses over 2 GB on x86 systems (without the 3GB switch) are in the kernel virtual address space.

Comment: thanks I didn't know that. Is it not possible then to read the transfer buffer this is pointing to?

Comment: No. Without the help of a kernel driver, this is not possible. But what do you want to do with this? How did you get a snapshot of this buffer from kernel mode?

Comment: I'm using a USB sniffing library (from HHD) and it calls a URB event and provides the packet. I'm trying to capture the raw data.

Comment: @ Richard: here's an MS page explaining MDL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463193
As Christopher said, you can only access it from a kernel driver

Comment: The sniffer tool will have some kind of interface to read the data in the MDL into user mode memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question...
TransferBufferMDL is used in DirectIO cases whereas TransferBuffer is for Buffered IO.

So one of those two will always be void.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep I know one of them will always be void, but the value is a large negative number which I'm assuming means I've read it in wrong somehow (I was expecting 0 for void).

Comment: Well, it is a pointer, so that is totally possible. any hex value bigger than 0x7FFFFFFF will show up as a negative number (highest bit is sign)

Comment: But isn't a pointer to a negative address invalid - or am I missing something?

Comment: No. Pointers > 0x7FFFFFFF are most likely in the kernel virtual address space.